# Renamed file appears in Github (remote repo)

Tags: github

I have been newly using GIT to start my Terraform journey. I was able to set my local repo and remote. Will everything working fine. However, i renamed a file in my local repo and did a commit. Then pushed it to remote repo in GITHUB.

The renamed file still appears in my Github (remote) repo along with the new one.

Copy of my commands :

```
xxxxxx MINGW64 /c/Data/Project/Terraform/Terraform (master)

    $ git status

On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    FirstTerraform.tf

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        Main.tf

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

xxxxxxx MINGW64 /c/Data/Project/Terraform/Terraform (master)
$ git add Main.tf

xxxxxxx MINGW64 /c/Data/Project/Terraform/Terraform (master)
$ git commit -m 'Changed file name'
[master 5254f64] Changed file name
1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 Main.tf

xxxxxx MINGW64 /c/Data/Project/Terraform/Terraform (master)
$ git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 468 bytes | 156.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 1 local object.
To https://github.com/xxxxxxxxx
   c397b99..5254f64  master -> master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't commit the file deletion. A rename in technical terms for Git is a `delete` and a `creation`. You've staged (i.e. you've prepared for commit) the `Main.tf` file, but you didn't stage the deletion: `FirstTerraform.tf`.

To solve this you simple need to run locally:

```
git add FirstTerraform.tf
git commit -m "Deleting FirstTerraform.tf"
git push origin master
```

If you're new to Git the `add` command can be a bit ambiguous, as you're actuality deleting a file but running a command to `add` it? Add in this sense means, staging the changes, or preparing them to be committed. I recommend studying the following diagram to understand Git file lifecycle:

[image]

Comment: Ahh my bad. I assumed it wasn't required even when i saw it as untracked. Thanks !!